# Calling and passing parameters from view to controller w/ select box and button

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm trying to order a table (without any plugin) in a Rails app. The idea is to retrieve a table from database and order it with 3 select box. After I click on the "Order" button and refresh page with ordered data.

I'm trying something and get this code:

```
def order
  @clients = Client.all(:order => 'parameter1, parameter2, parameter 3')
end
```

but, I have two questions:

1. How can I pass parameters from a `<select>` box to controller's method `order`?
2. How can I call this method and refresh the page with ordered data when I click the button?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the same controller action that renders the table now could be extended to handle the incoming sort options.  For example, it might be the current `index` method in your controller.

So build a form within your current page using `form_for`, with `select` helpers and a `submit` button that re-calls `index`.

Within the controller, you can access the values selected in the select boxes using the `params` hash that Rails sets for you.  For example, if your sorting parameters were "height",  "age", and "gender", in select lists `sort1`, `sort2` and `sort3` you might have code that does something like

```
def index
  sort_list = []
  # assumes the value of the sort list is the column name
  sort_list << params[:sort1] if params[:sort1]
  sort_list << params[:sort2] if params[:sort2]
  sort_list << params[:sort3] if params[:sort3]
  if sort_list.blank?
    @clients = Client.all
  else
    @clients = Client.all(:order => sort_list.join(", "))
  end
  ...
end
```

I know you said you didn't want a plugin (gem), but I have to mention a great one that rocks for even pretty complicated sorting (and filtering) called [ransack](https://github.com/ernie/ransack).

Comment: Thank you so much @tharrison !

This was exactly what I want!